# Prove: f is surjective -->$ f(f^{-1}(S)) = S$

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

I have to prove this exercise for my math-study:

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a function and $S \subseteq Y$

Prove: $f$ is surjective $\Rightarrow$ $f(f^{-1}(S)) = S$

I divided this exercise in two parts,
first proving that $S \subseteq f(f^{-1}(S))$.
This is what I did:

Assume $f$ is surjective $\Rightarrow$ $\forall s$  $\in S$ $\exists x \in$ $f^{-1}(S)$ such that $f(x) = s \Rightarrow s$ $\in$ $f(f^{-1}(S))$ $\Rightarrow$ $$S \subseteq f(f^{-1}(S))$$

Is this part right, or did I make any mistakes?

For the second part, I have to prove that $f(f^{-1}(S)) \subseteq S$

I began with this:

Assume $x$ $\in$ $f(f^{-1}(S))$. $f^{-1}(S)$ = {$x$ $\in$ X | $f(x)$ $\in$ S}

But I don't know how to prove from that that $x \in S$. Could you please help me with these two questions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the second part, if $x \in f(f^{-1}(S))$ then there is some $y \in f^{-1}(S)$ such that $f(y)=x$.  But $f(y) \in S$ by definition of pre-image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x\in f(f^{-1}(S))$, then $x = f(y)$ for some $y\in f^{-1}(S)$. So $f(y)\in S$, i.e., $x\in S$.

Conversely, if $x\in S$, then since $f$ is surjective, there exists a $u\in X$ such that $f(u) = x$. So $f(u)\in S$, which implies $u\in f^{-1}(S)$. Therefore $x = f(u)\in f(f^{-1}(S))$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at the second part comes from being a little more clear about notation.

Your function $f$ is a function, say, $f : X \to S$. Now, for *any* such function, $f^{-1}(S) \subseteq X$. Furthermore, for any subset $Y \subseteq X$, we have that $f(Y) \subseteq f(X) \subseteq S$. Putting these two pieces together, we find that $f(f^{-1}(S)) \subseteq S$ as claimed.